# Mirror a website with i18n

Tags: mirroring, i18n

I would like to know if there is any tool/software arround that is able to mirror a website translated in different languages.
In fact : the language choosen is stored in session so the software would need to be able to recognize the different content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is usually, depending on your webapplication, done via the browser language settings. You do not need to mirror the site in a different language.

If I will browse to a website/webapplication with the browser setting en_EN it will present to me the content in English.

If I have en_US (American English) it will do it in US translation, if there is such a language pack provided.

If the browser lang setting does not match any language it will fall back to the default language.